# Arbitrary Dictionary (JSON) to Stricter Tree-like Dictionary (JSON) in Python

Tags: python, json, recursion, tree, dictionary

Folks,

I have arbitrary dictionaries that may have any number of nesting of other dictionaries and arrays such as:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": "1",
        "c": [
            {
                "d": "2"
            },
            {
                "d": {
                    "e": "3",
                    "f": "4"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to represent this nicely as a tree, and in order to do that, I would like to convert it to a structure such as:

```
{
    "name": "a",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "b",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "c",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "d",
                    "value": "2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "d",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "e",
                            "value": "3"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "f",
                            "value": "4"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Doing so requires, I THINK, treating sub-dictionaries and sub-arrays similarly.  However, I am having a very hard time just coming up with an approach to do this transformation.  I have tried to work with recursion, and have also tried working with a node class that contains a key/value for "name", "value", and "children", but I am having a hard time parsing an arbitrarily deep input to create this regular node/tree representation.

Does this seem like something folks have done before?  Would appreciate your input.

Comment: Just wondering, is that a ExtJS tree that's being generated?

Comment: Jon, thanks for the message. I had not heard of ExtJS before your comment, looking into it now.  Truth be told, I am hoping to use the output for a data visualization using d3.js - the example i am working off is http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html

Comment: Wow - that's scary - i'm just working on something using `d3` as well - just need to finish the design first... I only asked because it looks like a nested tree thingy that I used ages ago using ExtJS (but only vaguely familiar, I tend to put JS stuff out of my head as soon as possible before it explodes :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You correctly identified this as a tree-like data structure, and it's very wise of you to transform it because the original representation is clearly and utterly broken.

Now that you know that you have a tree, you need to ask yourself what its nodes are. In your case, a node is either:

1. a leaf, which has a name and a value
2. an inner node, which has a name and children

The problem is that there are two different representation of the second type:

1. A pair `("<name>", { "<child1>" : ..., "<child2>" })`
2. A pair `("<name>", [{"<child1>" : ... }, { "<child2>": ... }])`

Your example doesn't show it, but maybe the following would also be possible:

`("<name>", [{"<child1>" : ... }, { "<child2>": ..., "<child3>": ... }])`

Recursion is indeed a good way to solve this. The edge case is clear, it's the leaf nodes. You just need to check the two other cases first:

```
def transform_node(name, val):
    if isinstance(val, list):
        val = ("children", [transform_node(k,v) for x in val for k, v in x.items()])
    elif isinstance(val, dict):
        val = ("children", [transform_node(*kv) for kv in val.items()])
    else:
        val = ("value", val)
    return dict([("name", name), val])
```

Now you get:

```
>>> transform_node("a", 3)
{'name': 'a', 'value': 3}
>>> transform_node("a", { "c1" : 3, "c2" : 4 })
{'name': 'a', 'children': [{'name': 'c2', 'value': 4}, {'name': 'c1', 'value': 3}]}
>>> transform_node("a", [{ "c1" : 3 }, { "c2" : 4, "c3": 5 }])
{'name': 'a', 'children': [{'name': 'c1', 'value': 3}, {'name': 'c3', 'value': 5}, {'name': 'c2', 'value': 4}]}
```

Perfect! Now you can just do:

```
>>> tree = { "a": { "b": 1 }}
>>> transform_node("root", tree)
{'name': 'root', 'children': [{'name': 'a', 'children': [{'name': 'b', 'value': 1}]}]}
```

Of course if you want "a" to be the root, you can then just extract the first child of the root.

That said, it's probably better to represent this as a real data type using classes, instead  of a dictionary, which is completly untyped.

Comment: Niklas, thank you! I am impressed.  Ran this against our basic example and it worked perfectly.  However, when running it against some real data, it errored.  after wrapping a try/except around the list branch, I can see that the place where this breaks is when an array is encountered that is not comprised of dict elements but rather just strings (i.e. ["a", "b"]).  working now to see if i can account for these cases by just generating a leaf node for each of these array elements.  Wow, you have really helped me a great deal here and I see I have a lot to learn about Python.

Comment: So there are also two different ways to represent a leaf node. That data really is pretty messed up :)